# cas-dc template and makecell package do not work together

Tags: tables

I am trying to use the makecell-package for multi-line content in tables. This works great with the standard latex class article. However, with the cas-dc package from elsevier, this does not work. In the bottom, you can find a minimum example. I get the (first) error

```
Misplaced \noalign. \thead{First Heading} & \thead
```

and a lot of similar erros after that.

Minimum example:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,english]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{makecell}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

%%%%%%
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\makeatletter                                                                   
\newlength{\bibsep}{\@listi \global\bibsep\itemsep \global\advance\bibsep by\parsep}
\makeatother   
% NEW END

\begin{document}
    \let\WriteBookmarks\relax
    \def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
    \def\textpagefraction{.001}
    \shorttitle{The CAS }
    \shortauthors{Elvis et~al.} 
    
    \title [mode = title]{Quantum teleportation in the context of industry 4.0}                      
    
    
    
    \author[1]{Elvis Presley}[auid=000,bioid=1]
    \cormark[1]
    % \fnmark[1]
    \ead{elvis-presley@skynet.ru}
    %\ead[url]{www.cvr.cc, cvr@sayahna.org}
    \credit{Software, Experiments}
    
    
    \begin{abstract}
        Quantum teleportation is a key technology for industry 4.0, 5G mobile communication and memristors. However, scientific journals with stupid latex templates waste the time of researchers. In this paper, the connection between these different research areas are discussed. For practical purposes, several blueprints for parameter optimisation are given. 
    \end{abstract}
    
    %\begin{graphicalabstract}
    %\includegraphics{figs/grabs.pdf}
    %\end{graphicalabstract}
    
    %\begin{highlights}
    %\item Research highlights item 1
    %\item Research highlights item 2
    %\item Research highlights item 3
    %\end{highlights}
    
    \begin{keywords}
        Latex  \sep Quantum Teleportation \sep Industry 4.0
    \end{keywords}
    
    
    \maketitle
    
    
    \begin{table*}[t]
        \caption{My table}
        \label{my_table}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \toprule
            % \textbf{First Heading} & \textbf{Second Heading} \\ % works
            \thead{First Heading} & \thead{Second \\ Heading} \\ % does not work
            \midrule
            First cell & Second cell \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}

    
    
    \section{Appendix}
    %Appendix sections are coded under \verb+\appendix+.
    %\verb+\printcredits+ command is used after appendix sections to list 
    %author credit taxonomy contribution roles tagged using \verb+\credit+ 
    %in frontmatter.
    \printcredits
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be you could try the `stackengine` package? There are circumstances where it works, and makecell doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `nicematrix` provides the command `\Block` that replaces `\multicolumn` and `m\ultirow`, and also allows the use of `\\` inside.

In this case  `\Block{}<\bfseries>{Second \\ Heading}` defines a 1x1 cell with two lines using bold font.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,english]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs}

%\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

%%%%%%
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\makeatletter                                                                   
\newlength{\bibsep}{\@listi \global\bibsep\itemsep \global\advance\bibsep by\parsep}
\makeatother   
% NEW END

\begin{document}
    \let\WriteBookmarks\relax
    \def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
    \def\textpagefraction{.001}
    \shorttitle{The CAS }
    \shortauthors{Elvis et~al.} 
    
    \title [mode = title]{Quantum teleportation in the context of industry 4.0}                      
    
    
    
    \author[1]{Elvis Presley}[auid=000,bioid=1]
    \cormark[1]
    % \fnmark[1]
    \ead{elvis-presley@skynet.ru}
    %\ead[url]{www.cvr.cc, cvr@sayahna.org}
    \credit{Software, Experiments}
    
    
    \begin{abstract}
        Quantum teleportation is a key technology for industry 4.0, 5G mobile communication and memristors. However, scientific journals with stupid latex templates waste the time of researchers. In this paper, the connection between these different research areas are discussed. For practical purposes, several blueprints for parameter optimisation are given. 
    \end{abstract}
    
    %\begin{graphicalabstract}
    %\includegraphics{figs/grabs.pdf}
    %\end{graphicalabstract}
    
    %\begin{highlights}
    %\item Research highlights item 1
    %\item Research highlights item 2
    %\item Research highlights item 3
    %\end{highlights}
    
    \begin{keywords}
        Latex  \sep Quantum Teleportation \sep Industry 4.0
    \end{keywords}
    
    
%   \maketitle
    

    \begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{My table}
    \label{my_table}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cc}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \toprule
        % \textbf{First Heading} & \textbf{Second Heading} \\ % works
        \Block{}<\bfseries>{First Heading} & \Block{}<\bfseries>{Second \\ Heading} \\ % also works!!
        \midrule
        First cell & Second cell \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}
    
    
    
    \section{Appendix}
    %Appendix sections are coded under \verb+\appendix+.
    %\verb+\printcredits+ command is used after appendix sections to list 
    %author credit taxonomy contribution roles tagged using \verb+\credit+ 
    %in frontmatter.
    \printcredits
    
\end{document}
```